# Change parent of a control in a size trigger in UWP

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm creating a Windows 10 Universal app, there are two panels in my main page.

In tablet/desktop mode, both are visible at the same time (just two simple `Grid`s, one fills the left side and the other one fills the right side)

However, in phone mode, there's a pivot and user can swipe between panels.

(I could use SplitView and hamburger menus which work easily in both Tablet/Desktop and Phone modes, but a pivot makes more sense in my case)

So, What I currently did is, I have two instances of each panel. `PhonePanel1` and `PhonePanel2` are two grids inside two pages of my pivot control, and `TabletPanel1` and `TabletPanel2` are two grids which can be shown side by side. and I use `AdaptiveTrigger`s to detect page width and switch between these two view methods.

However, having two instances of each panel is not a good approach, because those are showing basically the same content.

Is there any better approach to do this? Maybe changing Grid's parent when triggers are changing view mode? or something better?

Comment: What about Device Family specific views? You can define XAML for desktop/tablet and mobile separately. http://igrali.com/2015/08/02/three-ways-to-set-specific-devicefamily-xaml-views-in-uwp/

Comment: @Tomasz Pikć My worry with Device Family specific views (Which are a valid approach in some cases) is that AFAIK you would not get an adaptive/responsive UI when running the app in Continuum on a W10M phone. I would need to check but I assume if you use a family specific view that you would get the phone device family view showing on the external display?

Comment: @Mahdi did you decide on the best approach for your project in the end? I am duplicating controls still without any issues in performance. Deferring loading of the visuals until needed does seem to work well and it very quick to implement so I would say give it a go if you haven't already. If you need an example let me know and I can update my answer

Comment: @DanHarris Yes I used this method after all. Performance is good. The only problem is keeping scroll position of two views in sync (necessary for desktop, and portrait/landscape of large phones) which makes the code a little bit dirty. (what I did was finding the internal `ScrollViewer` inside `GridView`/`ListView` and reflecting scroll position changes in one of those (relatively) to the other via code behind. Is there a better way?)

Comment: @DanHarris Also, I forgot to select your answer as accepted. Thanks for reminding me :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to change the parent that I can think of is to write some code behind that will render them in the new location. A suitable solution may be to defer the loading of the controls until they are needed.

```
x:DeferLoadStrategy=”Lazy“
```

If you add this property to your controls that are duplicated, they will only be loaded when required. So on a phone the PC/Tablet view should never be loaded, unless the user is running in Continuum on an external display.

On a PC you may still end up with both loaded (If the user resizes the window) - On a PC there are usually more resources so it's *less* of a problem there in most cases.

I looked into the code behind approach to move the controls to a different parent and I think honestly it's premature to do that when it might not even improve performance.

I have gone for the Defer Load Strategy property and found performance to be fine, and it requires very little code. My duplicate controls are sharing the same ViewModel so I pretty much just added the property to ensure resources are only used when essential.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your approach. To reduce memory usage, when adaptive trigger happens for example on the phone, set TabletPanel1 and TabletPanel2 visibility to collapsed.

If all panels use the same datacontext then leave it as is, if not set datacontext for collapsed controls to null.

Answer (score -2):

You could create each of your panels as user controls then you've only need to define the contents once but each control could be included in each of the layouts you want.